# What are nice ways to draw a line of length $\pi$ if neusis is allowed?

Tags: geometry, pi, geometric-construction

I understand that a straight line of length $\pi$ can't be drawn with a compass and straight edge without neusis.

I'm looking for a nice way to draw a line of length $\pi$ using compass and straight edge, where neusis is allowed.

I saw that you can draw a circle of radius 1, draw a line through its diameter, wrap a string around your circle, mark the string where it crosses the diameter line, and then straighten the string.

However, I'd like to avoid that kind of wrapping/unwrapping if possible, as the materials I'm working with are rigid, hypothetically.

Cheers!

Edit: It's become clear from the great comments that neusis doesn't get you the transcendentals. So I'd also be interested in the following:

1. Other techniques which do give the transcendentals, in particular $\pi$, like the rope stretching technique mentioned above.
2. Compass and straight edge processes, which when repeated, rapidly approach a length of $\pi$.

Actually I think the comments are enough to set me on the right path, but answers are still welcome. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you mean *compass* and straightedge?

Comment: Oops! Yep. I'll change it. Cheers.

Comment: Compass and straight edge gives you rationals and square roots, neusis then gives you cube roots.  Neither can give you transcendentals.  See, e.g., [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31944/neusis-constructions).

Comment: Should say, there are a few different things that people might mean by neusis, or paper-folding, or the like.  But the conclusion doesn't really depend on the details.

Comment: @lulu Oh dang. Thanks lulu. So is the unwrapping method the only way around this? Or are there other techniques to mark transcendental lengths?

Comment: I don't know of any good method to do it...geometric constructions are intrinsically algebraic in nature.  I haven't thought about it, but I expect there's not even a sensible way to solve a general quintic, let alone attack transcendentals.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696569/i-think-i-found-a-method-for-squaring-the-circle-but-im-not-sure-if-its-valid

Comment: I have a very approximate construction to pi which has almost 0.0046% error. Shall I share it?

Comment: @SoumyadwipChanda That sounds great. I'd love to see it.

Comment: For people like me who haven't yet been introduced to this delicious (old) greek specialty : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neusis_construction

Comment: Whether or not neusis can construct a square with the area of a given circle was not definitely settled until 2002.

https://baragar.faculty.unlv.edu/papers/TwiceNotch.pdf

In sum (per Arthur Baragar), neusis can only construct certain algebraic numbers, which $\sqrt{\pi}$ is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I am demonstrating is a construction that gives us pi, approximately, with an error of 0.0046%.

Draw a circle of a known radius, preferably a power of 2 and draw a vertical diameter. I am drawing the circle of radius 2 units.

[image]

Now, draw a perpendicular line at point B and cut 3 times of the diameter. I name that point to be F

[image]

Now, construct an angle $30^o$ at A as shown and complete the triangle. I am not showing the arcs.

[image]

Join F and G and divide the line segments by the diameter. In this case it is 4. So I will bisect the line twice.

[image]

That construction does not yield $\pi$. The result is $\sqrt{9+(\frac12+\sqrt{\frac34})^2}$  From this geometric solution you can get $3.141737211$ (closer to $\pi$) but not actually $\pi$. This is to say, you get $0.0046$ % error which is acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

The following rational [approximations to pi](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiApproximations.html#:%7E:text=simplest%20approximants%20to-,.,12%2C%2013%2C%20...) from Wolfram are good to 2, 4, 6 and 9 decimal places respectively. 22/7, 333/106, 355/113, 103993/33102.

I think [this technique](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bn7P7-B3_mw) from YouTube for dividing a line using compass and straightedge will get you those indicated accuracies.

355/113 looks like the best effort to accuracy tradeoff. It gives 3.14159292035 versus 3.14159265359... for real pi. I think that's 0.99999991508 accuracy, or it overshoots pi by 0.0000002.66764189.

I still wish there was a way to apply an infinite series that approaches pi, using compass and straightedge to get arbitrarily close to pi with repeated applications of the procedure.

I think Nilakantha and Madhava's infinite series approximation to pi from this [diagram on Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f5/Comparison_pi_infinite_series.svg) and [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3U7Hfz37GqA&t=132) would work with the techniques mentioned above. Unfortunately this particular one takes 32 iterations to get the first 4 decimals of pi.

The formula is: 3 + 4/(2 x 3 x 4) - 4/(4 x 5 x 6) + 4/(6 x 7 x 8) - 4/(8 x 9 x 10) + ...